# What is the best practise for choosing unified ouput save_dir of distributable codes like PyPI packages

Tags: java, python, linux, windows, operating-system

I created a python package and uploaded it to PyPI. My package use a code that renders an output data file. The data file is saved to the same relative directory where the code is  :

```
output_data_file = open(Path.cwd() / "filename.txt", mode='w')
```

This code allows to correctly create a valid file in any OS. However the output location is not intuitive. In Ubuntu, it gives me a very long path like : ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/NameOfMyPackage/...

Is there instead a more intuitive way to create a shorter directory path that can be recognized by any Operating Systems. Like a root system path or  Documents/Deskop?

Comment: The current directory is not necessarily the directory of the package, unless your package manually changes the current directory, which generally it shouldn't do. The script directory should not intentionally be used. In many cases, the current user will not be allowed to create files there, and even if it's allowed for the current user (e.g. an admin), it's bad design. Otherwise using the current directory is fine in many cases, but it depends on usage. You can also use a known user directory, which can be determined using a package such as [userpaths](https://pypi.org/project/userpaths).

Comment: Thanks Eryk, something like userpaths was what is was looking for!